# Importing Express in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

What is the closest TypeScript equivalent of the following JavaScript code importing Express library and instantiating an application object:

```
// JavaScript    
const app = require("express")();
```

I understand that I can use something like the following to achieve this but it takes more lines of code:

```
// TypeScript
import express from "express";
const app: express.Application = express();
```

Or this too, but again more lines.

```
// TypeScript
import * as express from "express";
const app: express.Application = express.default();
```

Comment: No, not possible otherwise

Comment: I thought I was the perfectionist )

Comment: You probably don't need the explicit type annotation, the compiler will infer the type of `app`